# If I modify a note locally in Tomboy, can I upload those changes into the notes in UbuntuOne?

Tags: ubuntu-one, tomboy, notes

When I try to upload a new notes or changes using the Synch function of Tomboy, I only get the option to rename local notes or to replace them, but no to replace those notes on the cloud. Is this supposed to be like this? is it  there a fix? 
Running Tomboy 1.8.0. Ubuntu v11.10 up-to-date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution under test: Assign an specific notebook to your notes and you should be able to synchronize them (commit and download changes).

Edit: After two months seems to be working fine. Tested with two computers through ubuntu one.

Comment: You can accept your answer by clicking on the check mark if it works for you. Thanks! :)